.NET 8 : context.User.IsInRole always return false
I use .NET 8.0 and custom IdentityContext like this
IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>

I write
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>

and
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>

iamge1
then in program.cs, I have:
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(o =>
            {
                o.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "Role";
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

imge22
Of course, in my database, I have admin user and Admin role.
I code sample CategoriesController and use auth with Roles = "admin"
image2
Then I tried it but I got error
image3
Claims has Role  = "Admin" but always returns false
imge4
img5
Please help me - I have no idea how to fix this.
I tried some ways but can't make it work, I know I can create customAuthorize but I want to know why and how to fix this for next project

Hey and welcome. Can you share the content of your images as text. It's easier to read and to help.

According to the img5, I see the user is not authenticated  which means it doesn't pass the authentication, could you please tell me how you send the request with the user credential to the web api? Did you set it well?
